# I cant take the values inside context in other components

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm starting to work with react now and I was taking a course but in the context part mine is not giving the same result as it should can someone help me with that, my codes:

Context.jsx

```
import { useState,createContext } from "react";

export const Contexto = createContext([]);

export default function ContextoGlobal(props){
    const [usuario,setUsuario] = useState({
        nome:"",
        logado:false
    });

    return(
        <Contexto.Provider value={{usuario,setUsuario}}>
            {props.children}
        </Contexto.Provider>
    );
}
```

index.js

```
...
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ContextoGlobal>
      <App/>
    </ContextoGlobal>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
...
```

calling context

```
const Usuario= useContext(Contexto);
User=Usuario.usuario
setUser=Usuario.setUser
alert(Usuario.usuario.nome)
let sla=Usuario.usuario.nome
```

to get the context values ​​in the course the guy used this code

```
const {user,setUser}= useContext(Context)
```

and with that he was able to use the set function and the user object

When I try this, it is undefined, only allowing access in the way I showed:

```
User=Usuario.usuario
setUser=Usuario.setUser
alert(Usuario.usuario.nome)
```

but that way I can't use the setUser function

Answer (score 0):

You provide `usuario` and `setUsuario` to the `value` of the context inside a object `{}`. You can use your context like this:

```js
const { usuario, setUsuario } = useContext(Contexto);
```

If you `console.log()` your context value you'll see that it is a object with the two values you set

```js
const Usuario = useContext(Contexto);
console.log(Usuario);

// {
//   usuario: {
//     nome: "",
//     logado: false,
//   },
//   setUsuario: () => {}, // set state
// }
```

It also might be good to initiate your content value with a object `{}` instead of a array `[]` since that is what you're going to set in the Provider

```js
export const Contexto = createContext({});
```